# Which technology is used to develop working platforms like goDaddy, wix and other web page development sites

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am trying to develop a `web application` that will have user-editable webpages. Any user post **authorization** will be able to `edit` not only the `text` but almost any `tag` on the page that too without writing any code just like in **go daddy** or **wix**.

Can anyone tell me which **technology**, **language** or **framework** is used by websites like `go daddy` or `wix`?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not one technology but a set of technologies (It's a web based project, then consider web technologies). If you already know HTML, CSS, JavaScript, understanding how the drag and drop concept works is mandatory. You can use [DraggableJS](https://shopify.github.io/draggable/) as a drag and drop framework.

But There are lot of frameworks that can help you go with your project directly and the one I can suggest is [GrappesJS](https://grapesjs.com/)

Basically JavaScript will help you generate the current user page content (the page that the user is modifying) and you can manage that page content (actually a text based content) as any other user content on your server. There are lot of complexities to manage there, for example if a user added external resources to their page, you may need to keep references to those resources.

When the user clicks on publish, depending on your philosophy, their website folder should contain the website files as it should be with the traditional way, at that point you need to write the website pages into files on the website folder.

If that can help, good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been checking it out and i can see that it will help, I'm trying to use it, using the link on their website in my HTML link tag but it does not seem to be responding. I am not sure if it means I have to download it or i  can only just reference it in my HTML. Please tell me, does it need to be downloaded or the i just paste the link my HTML?

Comment: The reason i ask is because my HTML is only linked to my js and css files and to grapes because the changes I'm making do not reflect. It is like my program is not linked with GrapesJS

Comment: great @lehlohonolosefako, so if you find the answer useful, do you mind accept it for future reference?